# Nuxt 3 Images not rendered when set the src dynamically on build process

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

:I have the following problem with a Nuxt3 application.
When set an image source via `template strings` the build process will not render the images.
Otherwise it will, when i set the image src normally. But i need it dynamically.
There are teasers with different images that need to be rendered.

Everythung is working fine, e.g. props ...

The working code:

```
...
<img
  src="/assets/_DSC0238_E.jpg"
  :alt="props.name"
  class="w-full aspect-square object-cover"
  :class="`aspect-${props.aspectRatio}`"
/>
...
```

The not working code:

```
...
<img
  :src="`props.image`"
  :alt="props.name"
  class="w-full aspect-square object-cover"
  :class="`aspect-${props.aspectRatio}`"
/>
...
```

What is the way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

### In case you are using `Nuxt 3` with `Vite` as Bundler

Set Assets composable.

```
export default function useAssets() {
  const svgs = import.meta.globEager('/src/assets/*.svg');
  const pngs = import.meta.globEager('/src/assets/*.png');
  const jpegs = import.meta.globEager('/src/assets/*.jpeg');

  return {
    aboutImage: svgs['/src/assets/aboutImage.svg'].default,
    search: svgs['/src/assets/search.svg'].default,
    info: pngs['/src/assets/info.png'].default,
  }; 
}
```

Then in any file:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <img :src="assets.info">
    </div>
</template>
  
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/runtime-core';
import useAssets from '../composable/useAssets';
  
export default defineComponent({
setup() {
  const assets = useAssets();
    return {
      assets,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

[resource](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1265)

### In case (Vu3, Vue2, Nuxt 2) and bundler is `Webpack`

You need to `require` the image path, and set a dynamic `src` attribute by adding a colon before `:src`

```
<img
  :src="require(`~/assets/${props.image}`)"
  :alt="props.name"
  class="w-full aspect-square object-cover"
  :class="`aspect-${props.aspectRatio}`"
/>
```

### In case (Vu3, Vue2, Nuxt 2) and bundler is `Vite`

```
const getImage = async imgName => {
  // set the relative path to assets
  const module = await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `../../assets/${imagName}`)
  return module.default.replace(/^\/@fs/, '')
}

<img
  :src="getImage(props.image)"
  :alt="props.name"
  class="w-full aspect-square object-cover"
  :class="`aspect-${props.aspectRatio}`"
/>
```

Comment: I always tried this as well. But it throws that `require is not defined`

Comment: I think you are using `vite` as a bunder, I update the answer, please check.

Comment: Your idea with the getImage method will also not work. There is no output in the img tag.
The images are rendered, i can see it in the network tab. But not in the DOM.

Comment: I update the answer again.

Answer (score -2):

we can use v-bind to assign them a string value dynamically. [read this](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)

Try like this:

```
<img
 v-bind:src="require(`@/assets/${props.image}`)"
 :alt="props.name"
 class="w-full aspect-square object-cover"
 :class="`aspect-${props.aspectRatio}`"
/>
```

or for shorthand syntax

```
<img
 :src="require(`@/assets/${props.image}`)"
 :alt="props.name"
 class="w-full aspect-square object-cover"
 :class="`aspect-${props.aspectRatio}`"
/>
```

Comment: I edited my post. I used the shorthand syntax for v-bind

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).