# How to pass dynamic image url in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I would like to pass a dynamic image url in Nuxt 3.
This is how it used to work in Nuxt 2:
**Example Childcomponent.vue: **

```
\<template\> \<NuxtLink \> \<img :src="require(`@/static/media/${work.image}.png\`)" alt=""\>
\</NuxtLink\>
\</template\>

\<script\>
export default {
props: {
work: {
type: Object,
required: true,
},
}
}
\</script\>\
```

**Parent component: **

```
\`\<template\>

  
          <CardsCaseCard 
            :work="work" 
          />
  



export default {
name: 'CaseList',
data() {
return {
works: \[
{
id: 1,
image: 'office-1'
},
{
id: 2,
image: 'office-2'
},
{
id: 3,
image: 'office-3'
},
\]
}
}
}
\</script\>\`
```

Does anyone know how to pass the images in Nuxt 3?

I have seen some solutions e.g. here: [Nuxt 3 Images not rendered when set the src dynamically on build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497705/nuxt-3-images-not-rendered-when-set-the-src-dynamically-on-build-process)

But it is still not clear to me how this works with an array of images.

Comment: Can you format the code in your question so that it is readable?

Comment: since your placing them in [static directory](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/public) it would be `:src="`/media/${work.image}.png`"`, or since the array is hard-coded you could require them directly in its creation to *bundle* them, if its a not hard-coded array, then *bundling* images on the fly like after being uploaded is not possible, your want to set the path to where the image is being served from, i.e leaving out the require call